# convert date string of yyyy-mm-dd into date.now object for datepicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make my datepicker work in mobile, while in desktop I am converting the date to a specific format as below,

```
  format(new Date(), "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

This is returning a date string like this,

```
date string:  2022-08-02 string
```

I am trying to convert it to be used with this datepicker, while using the existing functions.

Currently this is something like this,

```
export default function DatePick({ startDate,   setSelectedDate,}) {

    const toDate = (dateStr) => {
        const [day, month, year] = dateStr.split("-")
        return new Date(year, month - 1, day)
      }

    const [datePicked,setDatePicked] = useState(toDate(startDate)) 

//convertfrom dd-mm-yyy to date object like Date.Now()


    const handleClick = ({ day }) => {
        setSelectedDate(day)
        setDatePicked(toDate(startDate))
      };

   
      console.log("date string: ",startDate, typeof startDate)


  return (
    <div>
      <div className="flex items-center mx-auto space-x-4">
        <div className="flex flex-row relative">
        <DatePicker selected={datePicked} onChange={handleClick} />

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

However, on clicking a date, I am receiving an error of

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')
```

when casting the object into .toString, i.e.,

```
        const [day, month, year] = dateStr.toString().split("-")
```

I am still receiving an error of invalid function call.

Confused how to solve this issue - surely casting it to a string value should be fine?

Comment: how do you pass startDate to DatePick ?

Comment: using         setDatePicked(toDate(startDate)) inside handleClick

Comment: @LeCoda `setDatePicked` is part of the component `DatePick`. `DatePick` has, as props, 2 values, `startDate` and `setSelectedDate`. This means that somewhere, some other component should instantiate DatePick like `<DatePick startDate="..." setSelectedDate={...}/>`. I suppose Krzysztof was asking how you are passing the startDate prop to the component from the outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `toDate` function to the following:

```
    const toDate = (dateStr) => {
        if (!dateStr)
           return new Date();
        const [day, month, year] = dateStr.split("-")
        return new Date(year, month - 1, day)
      }
```

This will make the current date default if no date is predefined.

Comment: this doesn't solve the issue of not being able to split the string

Comment: @LeCoda, can you share your `DatePicker` component? It seems to be originated from that component.